# Cx_Oracle equivalent of on duplicate key update

Tags: python, oracle, merge

Now I have a list of tuple named "Data"

```
[
('171115090000',
Timestamp('2017-11-15 09:00:00'),
'PAIR1',
156.0)
]
```

I want to insert this list to Oracle DB, my code is

```
cur.executemany(
            '''INSERT INTO A 
            ("SID","DATE","ATT","VALUE") 
            VALUES(:1,:2,:3,:4)''',Data)
```

And it works well. However if I want to add/replace new records into this database, I have to create a table B to put those records then merge A and B.

Is there anything like on duplicate key update that I could finish my job without creating a new table?

I know I could select all records from A, convert them to a DataFrame and merge DataFrames in Python, is this a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there anything like on duplicate key update

In Oracle, it is called `MERGE`; have a look at the following example:

Table contents at the beginning:

```
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
```

MERGE statement:

```
SQL> merge into dept d
  2    using (select deptno, dname, loc
  3           from (select 10 deptno, 'ACC' dname, 'NY' loc from dual --> already exists, should be updated
  4                 union all
  5                 select 99       , 'NEW DEPT' , 'LONDON' from dual --> doesn't exists, should be inserted
  6                )
  7          ) x
  8  on (d.deptno = x.deptno)
  9  when matched then update set
 10                      d.dname = x.dname,
 11                      d.loc   = x.loc
 12  when not matched then insert (d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc)
 13                        values (x.deptno, x.dname, x.loc);

2 rows merged.
```

The result: as you can see, values for existing `DEPTNO = 10` were updated, while the new `DEPTNO = 99` was inserted into the table.

```
SQL> select * From dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACC            NY
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
        99 NEW DEPT       LONDON

SQL>
```

I don't speak Python so I can't compose code you might use, but I hope that you'll manage to do it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact I'd like to know how to merge a table and data, without creating a temp table (at least not explicitly). Now I gave up and use the method you've mentioned.

Comment: I still want to see if someone who speak Python would give me a better solution so please allow me to leave this question open.

Comment: Absolutely; I hope someone else will be able to assist.